# Как использовать асинхронную функцию внутри задачи celery?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, task, celery

Я пишу бот в айограм, нашел несколько похожих вопросов, но не смог найти то, что мне нужно.
У меня есть асинхронная функция, которую я хочу использовать в своей задаче celery, но не могу вызвать ее внутри задачи. Есть ли способ сделать это?
**db.py**

```
async def select_users():
    sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE "
    sql, parameters = self.format_args(sql, parameters=kwargs)
    return await self.execute(sql, *parameters, fetchrow=True)
```

**tasks.py**

```
from .celery import app
import db

@app.task
def update_credits():
    users = db.select_users()  #как вызвать асинхронную функцию?
    print(users)
```

Answer (score 0):

Пока не очень хочется залезать в celery, но если там обычные воркеры, то должно сработать:

```
from .celery import app
import db
import asyncio

@app.task
def update_credits():
    users = asyncio.run(db.select_users())
    print(users)
```

Если не прокатит, то напиши в комментариях ошибку... есть ещё варианты.

П.с. обрати внимание на self - она не определенна.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Я пробовал этот метод, но получил ошибку, теперь использую aioshcedular